# no console output in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using windows 7 32- bit and eclipse juno for cpp programming . When I tried to run the "Hell World" program, it is showing no console output. The program builds without any error. can anyone suggest a solution?

*(Code pasted from comment)*

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{
  cout<<"HELLO WORLD"<<endl;  
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 cout<<"HELLO WORLD"<<endl;

}

Comment: Try running it from terminal, not from inside Eclipse.

Comment: -1 for poor research. It was the first result on google: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/

Comment: only a helloworld.exe in the debug folder and it works

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried that too, but its not working

Comment: Eclipse, if I recall correctly, has several types of console windows (some show just build info and not the result of the program run). Are you sure you are looking at the right console window?

Comment: it worked when I started with a fresh copy of eclipse, thank you all

Answer (score 2):

It's an [eclipse bug](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Eclipse_console_does_not_show_output_on_Windows). You need to add:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

to the start of main.

Comment: There is a lot of information on the link StoryTeller posted you should check it out

Comment: it worked when I started with a fresh copy of eclipse, thank you all